# Run bundle install after adding/removing a new gem when using docker-compose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker and was trying to integrate docker with my rails app. I was following this [doc](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/containerizing-a-ruby-on-rails-application-for-development-with-docker-compose)

I was able to setup the services but I am facing a problem.

Whenever I add a Gem to my Gemfile I get error in `docker-compose up` saying

```
sidekiq_1  | bundler: failed to load command: sidekiq (/usr/local/bundle/bin/sidekiq)
sidekiq_1  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/bundler-2.2.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:309:in `block in verify_gemfile_dependencies_are_found!': Could not find gem 'awesome_print' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:3.0.0-alpine3.12

ENV BUNDLER_VERSION=2.2.3

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
      binutils-gold \
      build-base \
      curl py-pip \
      curl \
      file \
      g++ \
      gcc \
      git \
      less \
      libstdc++ \
      libffi-dev \
      libc-dev \
      linux-headers \
      libxml2-dev \
      libxslt-dev \
      libgcrypt-dev \
      make \
      netcat-openbsd \
      nodejs \
      openssl \
      pkgconfig \
      python3 \
      tzdata \
      yarn

RUN gem install bundler -v 2.2.3

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./

RUN bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries

RUN bundle check || bundle install

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install --check-files

COPY . ./

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.6'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: sna-main
    depends_on:
      - redis
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.7

  sidekiq:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - app
      - redis
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - gem_cache:/usr/local/bundle/gems
      - node_modules:/app/node_modules
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
    entrypoint: ./entrypoints/sidekiq-entrypoint.sh

volumes:
  gem_cache:
  node_modules:
```

It would be great if someone can help me out to understand how to run bundle install every time there is a change in Gemfile.

From the doc I have understood that because we are caching the Gems so we need to remove the volume explicitly if we add/remove a new gem.

I did remove the volumes by running `docker-compose down -v`.
It removed the volumes but still getting the same error.

Comment: You should delete all of the `volumes:` so that you're using the code built into the image.  In particular the volume mount over `/usr/local/bundle/gems` will cause Docker to use an old version of that directory and ignore any changes you make in your service's `Gemfile`.

Comment: @DavidMaze - I am using `docker-compose down -v` to remove all the volumes but still when running `docker-compose up` having same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work by adding `bundle install` in my entrypoint file

----------------./entrypoints/docker-entrypoint.sh-----------------

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle install
bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

----------------./entrypoints/sidekiq-entrypoint.sh-----------------

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ -f tmp/pids/server.pid ]; then
  rm tmp/pids/server.pid
fi

bundle install && bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance that this is because docker-compose cached your images; you need to re-build with `docker-compose up --build` to reflect the image changes in docker-compose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately it dint work out.

I did find a way by adding `bundle install` in my entrypoint file